# SearchView Widget is not working properly

Tags: android, listview, android-widget, searchview

I am trying to filter my listview using searchview acitonbar widget, but when i type something  in edittext a black box is appeared on screen. How to make search without that black box.
[image]

here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnQueryTextListener{

    private Button favListBtn;
    private ListView mListView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] categories =  {"Food", "Cloth", "Shoes","Agriculture",
                                "Food", "Cloth", "Shoes","Agriculture",
                                "Food", "Cloth", "Shoes","Agriculture",
                                "Food", "Cloth", "Shoes","Agriculture",
                                "Food", "Cloth", "Shoes","Agriculture",
                                "Food", "Cloth", "Shoes","Agriculture",
                                "Food", "Cloth", "Shoes","Agriculture"};

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView = getListView();

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapte = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapte);
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {

                      new SearchAsynTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
                      // selected item 
                      String category = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BusinessListActivity.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, category, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
            });       
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {        

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query))
          {
                mListView.clearTextFilter();
            }
          else
          {
                mListView.setFilterText(query.toString());
            }
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think it's because of youre  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, category, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 0):

It is showing that black box because you set the list view to do so:        `mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);`

**EDIT:**
You said you couldn't make the search without the above line. It is because you are using text filtering for search purpose. This is not a good way. You are calling `mListView.setFilterText(query.toString());` in `onQueryTextChange()` callback. So without enabling the text filtering, your search mechanism does not work.

The proper way is to make your ListView Adapter implement [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface and handle the filtering there.

Then you should do the search on the [Filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) object: `Filter.performFiltering(CharSequence)`

Comment: without this line, i can't search in my listview.